# Custom group and sort asp:listview datasource xml using XSLT

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt

I have a listview which gets an xmldatasource as its datasource. The xmldatasource is created and assigned dynamically. Using xpath just before binding the data to the listview using

```
 listview.datasource = myxmlsource
listview.DataBind()
```

only the node element is selected using `xpath="root/node"` .Hence I think the xml structure after the xpath is applied looks like the following:

```
<node name="Albert" age="32" desc="some random description" region="north"/>
<node name="Randy" age="32" desc="some random description" region="south"/>
<node name="Zebra" age="32" desc="some random description"region="east"/>
<node name="Bob" age="32" desc="some random description"region="south"/>
<node name="Carl" age="32" desc="some random description"region="north"/>
<node name="Denver" age="32" desc="some random description"region="east"/>
```

Note that it has no root. I'm trying to sort this XSLT.

> The aim here is to group the xml by region and then sort the xml by
>   name.

I'm new to XSLT and it seems to be quite a beast.

so far the xslt code I could come up with is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl my" xmlns:my="http://tempuri.org"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template name="@*|node()">

      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node() >
          <xsl:sort select="@region" order="ascending"/>
          <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>    
    </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The expected output after grouping by region and sorting by name is:

```
<node name="Denver" age="32" desc="some random description"region="east"/>
<node name="Zebra" age="32" desc="some random description"region="east"/>
<node name="Albert" age="32" desc="some random description" region="north"/>
<node name="Carl" age="32" desc="some random description"region="north"/>
<node name="Bob" age="32" desc="some random description"region="south"/>
<node name="Randy" age="32" desc="some random description" region="south"/>
```

**Update:**

I forgot to mention:
The ordering of the grouping by region need not necessarily be ascending or descending but can be based on any custom condition such as north first, east second and south third. How to achieve a custom ordering?

I tried the following and some more stuff similar and I get

> This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
      <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node[@region='north']" >
              <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:copy>    
           <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node[@region='east']" >
              <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:copy>    
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node[@region='south']" >
              <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:copy>  
        </xsl:template>    

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XSLT is almost right - the template should have a `match="..."` instead than a `name="..."` attribute - here is the working version:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl my" xmlns:my="http://tempuri.org"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
        <xsl:sort select="@region" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```